# how to make a loop that shows data from database into react-data-table-component using php and react

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

This is the table.js component:

```
import "../styles/Table.css";
import React from "react";
// import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";
import DataTableExtensions from "react-data-table-component-extensions";
import "react-data-table-component-extensions/dist/index.css";

import { columns, data } from "./data";

function Table() {
  const tableData = {
    columns,
    data
  };
  const [datas, setData] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost/backend2/courrier.php")
      .then((res) => res.json()).then(data =>{
        console.log(data.data)
        let ms  = data.msg;
      })
      .then((datas) => 
      setData(datas.message));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <DataTableExtensions {...tableData}>
        <DataTable
          columns={columns}
          data={data}
          noHeader
          defaultSortField="id"
          defaultSortAsc={false}
          pagination
          highlightOnHover
        />
      </DataTableExtensions>
    </div>
  );
}

  
export default Table;
```

The table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8MVG.png
And this is data.js where the data shown in the table is stored:

```
import React from "react";

export const columns = [
  {
    name: "Numéro d'ordre",
    selector: "num",
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name: "Date de départ",
    selector: "date",
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name: "Destinaire",
    selector: "destinaire",
    sortable: true,
    // cell: d => <span>{d.genres.join(", ")}</span>
  },
  {
    name: "Objet",
    selector: "objet",
    sortable: true
  }
];

export const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    num: "1001",
    objet: "Paiments",
    destinaire: "3310 Rue de la libérté",
    date: "25/09/2022",},
  {
     id: 2,
     num: "1002",
     objet: "Transfert d'employés",
     destinaire: "201 Rue Habib Bourguiba",
     date: "27/09/2022",},
];

export default data;
```

this is the php file:

```
<?php
require 'config.php' ; 


$sql = 'select * from courrier' ; 

$query = $conn->query($sql) ;

$data = array() ; 

while($item = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = $item ; 
}

$output = array() ;

if(count($data)>0){
    $output['msg'] = 'data here' ;
    $output['data'] = $data;
} else {
    $output['msg'] = 'data not here' ;
}

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

And I want the data from the database courrierdb made using xamp and phpmyadmin to be shown inside the table component.
I thought about storing data inside a list and looping it inside data.js but I don't know the code to do so. Is it possible using this react-data-table-component?

Comment: I am a bit lost in the question, can you summarize what you need exactly? It looks like you got your data into the table, do you want to sort them or what?

Comment: I have data in a database and I want to show that data in the table instead of using the data written in data.js
Cause right now the table is showing rows from data.js file and I want to link it to my database.

Comment: But in this line `fetch("http://localhost/backend2/courrier.php")` you're already fetching data from database, so what exactly you need?

Comment: @Sanidhya I want to make the data show inside the table

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(data.data)`? Pls share a screenshot if possible.